# How does one enable system paste in vim using zsh shell in Ubuntu?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, zsh

I've recently changed shell from bash to zsh and I'm having a problem in vim, in that my system paste no longer works. Before changing shell, I was able to paste from my system clipboard using `=+p` but now for some reason, unknown to me, the `-` and `+` keys are now bound to go up a line and down a line respectively, stopping paste from working.

I'm also using [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) plugin manager for zsh and my operating system is Ubuntu Linux.

I can post my `.zshrc` and `.vimrc` on request, although there are no recent changes to my `.vimrc`.

I'm not sure what is causing the `+` and `-` key mappings and I would like to know how to re-enable system paste functionality?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you said `=+p` did you mean `"+p`?

Comment: Yes! That was my mistake all along, I don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: Why is this off-topic?  What is more pertinent to programming than the editor one uses to write programs with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A "safer" way to paste from the system clipboard is to use the OS-wide paste-combo <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>insert</kbd>. It's equivalent for copying is <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>insert</kbd>. It works on pretty much every platform and doesn't care how you've set up your clipboard. I'm not sure if it plays nicely with Gvim though, atleast it doesn't on Windows.

Adding to that, you may want to toggle `paste` mode when doing a paste so it doesn't try to interpret and align whatever you're pasting. Toggle it insert mode by pressing <kbd>F3</kbd>:

```
set pastetoggle=<F3>
```

*This does however not answer your question as to why the behaviour has changed, but it might be nice to know anyway.*

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I've added that to my `.vimrc`. Using the OS-wide paste combo doesn't always work properly, without that, in vim. I think I'm going to accept your this question because it has somehow resolved itself and returned to normal behaviour. Although, I would still be interested to know what might have caused it.

Comment: @silleknarf If it pastes anything, it's working as intended, even if it'll indent whatever is pasted in an odd way. This is because Vim interprets it as normal input and tries to understand it, but in most cases fails. Thank you for the accept, but it'd be interesting to see why zsh/ohmyzsh could break something like this. If you find out why, do post why :-)

Comment: See the comment on the question, silly error on my part!